# child class to filter parent class by condition in sqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, single-table-inheritance

In flask-sqlAlchemy, I have a class `User`, which has, amongst others, the column `status`, like so:

```
class User(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    status = Column(String(255))
    age = Column(Integer)
    yet_another_property = Column(String(255))
```

I would now like to have a model `ActiveUser` which represents all entries in the `user` table where `status` is `'active'`. Spoken in MySQL, this would be

```
SELECT * FROM user 
    WHERE
       user.status = 'active';
```

I think, this should somehow work with `ActiveUser` being a child class of `User` and via single table inheritance (as described at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance), like so:

```
class User(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    status = Column(String(255))
    age = Column(Integer)
    yet_another_property = Column(String(255))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on':status,
        'polymorphic_identity':'user'
    }

class ActiveUser(User):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on':status,
        'polymorphic_identity':'active'
    }
```

My first question is: **Would this work?**

It gets a bit more complicate, since actually I want to filter on *multiple* properties. So, actually, I want to have a class `ActiveAdultUser`, which represents all Users being in `active` status and having an age greater or equal 18. Again, spoken in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM user 
    WHERE
       user.status = 'active'
    AND
       user.age >= 18;
```

My second question is: **So, how would I do *that*?**

Of course I know, I can do queries for active adult `Users` by applying `.filter(and_(User.status == 'active', User.age >=18))` to a query on `User`. But for the sake of clean code I would like to have this filter on the Model level.

I also thought of overriding the query function on the `ActiveUser` model, but this looks rather hacky and I don't know if I can rely on this in any circumstance.

Comment: Just modified my answer below to include some ideas how to reduce redundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can produce [multiple mappers for one class](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html#multiple-mappers-for-one-class) – found in the [non-traditional mappings](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/nonstandard_mappings.html) section of the documentation:

> However, there is a class of mapper known as the **non primary** mapper with allows additional mappers to be associated with a class, but with a limited scope of use. This scope typically **applies to being able to load rows from an alternate table or selectable unit**, but still producing classes which are ultimately persisted using the primary mapping.

So instead of a subclass you'd produce a non primary mapper `ActiveUser`:

```
In [9]: ActiveUser = mapper(
   ...:     User,
   ...:     User.__table__.select().
   ...:         where(User.status == "active").
   ...:         alias(),
   ...:     non_primary=True)
   ...:     

In [10]: print(session.query(ActiveUser))
SELECT anon_1.id AS anon_1_id, anon_1.status AS anon_1_status, anon_1.age AS anon_1_age, anon_1.yet_another_property AS anon_1_yet_another_property 
FROM (SELECT user.id AS id, user.status AS status, user.age AS age, user.yet_another_property AS yet_another_property 
FROM user 
WHERE user.status = ?) AS anon_1
```

On the other hand all of this might be rather unnecessary and you could simply query for active users when you need such.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can do that with polymorphic as you cannot put a "greater than" comparison there.  You can only have a fixed polymorphic_identity. You also cannot polymorph on two different fields, only one.

To me this is a case where you are planning to "simplify" something that is already relatively simple.  An SQL query with two filtering conditionals is hardly a complicated or even a messy statement.

If you are adamant you want to do this, the correct method is to subclass `Query` and write your conditional in there.  https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/PreFilteredQuery gives an example how to do this.

Personally I would just add two filters to my queries. It is far less messy and fragile than subclassing something that may change in the future versions. Query syntax is likely to be far more persistent.

Another way of removing redundant code would be prewriting the query:

```
q = (User.age >= 18, User.status == "active")
foo = Session.query(User).filter(*q).all()
```

or even

```
q = Session.query(User).filter(User.age >= 18, User.status == "active")
foo = q.filter(add your additional filters here).all()
# or if no additional filters needed
foo = q.all()
```

If you define q in a suitable place of your code, you can use it throughout your program. This would remove the need to repeat those two filtering conditions in every query.

Comment: I personally have not found much use for polymorphic at all. If I have a table with objects of different kind, I just add another table "kind" and a foreign key to that.   One "problem" with polymorphic is handling all possible values. Polymorphic moans at runtime if you have an unhandled situation. If you only build a polymorphic on "active", you will get run time warnings if there is something else in that field and you do not have a class for that alternative. You can ignore them but programs tend to produce a lot of gobbledygook in logs because of this.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good fit for a prefiltered query, which is usually used for things like soft delete. A non primary mapper against a SELECT might be a better match, if one insists on having "subclasses" (not really though). On the other hand non primary mappers are only mentioned in relation to complex relationship configurations in the docs, so might not work here.

Comment: This does not seem like a good fit for anything really as the original case is already as simple as it gets. I would personally avoid all attempts to simplify that by adding complexity elsewhere.